# What is holding onto my controllers?

Tags: ios, memory-management, getter-setter, pushviewcontroller

I'd built an app under Xcode 4.3 beta using the Master/Detail template and ARC, then found I could not submit it, so back ported it to Xcode 4.2, adding all the memory management.
It's not leaking, but the profiler says is is growing each time I visit a detail record from the master display--one detail controller each time.

I've declared the controller as an ivar and a property in the Master (root) controller (synthasized in the .m file):

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> {
...
    @private
    DetailViewController *detailViewController;
}
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) DetailViewController *detailViewController;
@end

...
@synthasize detailViewController;
```

New instances are created on selection of a master list item in the -tableView:didselectRowAtIndexPath call (NSLog's added to show progressive retain count):

```
tableView:didselectRowAtIndexPath call (NSLog's added to show progressive retain count):
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"1 dvc %i",[self.detailViewController retainCount]);
    self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"2 dvc %i",[self.detailViewController retainCount]);
    NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    detailViewController.detailItem = selectedObject;    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"3 dvc %i",[self.detailViewController retainCount]);
    [self.detailViewController release];
    NSLog(@"4 dvc %i",[self.detailViewController retainCount]);
}
```

To my way of thinking, this should have correctly managed the object lifecycle and to check, I put another NSLog in the RootViewController -viewWillAppear method to see that the retain count was each time the Root (Master) view appears. The debug log is showing the following:

```
2011-09-20 15:17:34.402 ABRA[13133:207] RootViewController viewDidAppear DVC=0
2011-09-20 15:17:38.410 ABRA[13133:207] 1 dvc 0
2011-09-20 15:17:38.411 ABRA[13133:207] 2 dvc 2
2011-09-20 15:17:38.467 ABRA[13133:207] 3 dvc 9
2011-09-20 15:17:38.468 ABRA[13133:207] 4 dvc 8
2011-09-20 15:17:41.889 ABRA[13133:207] RootViewController viewDidAppear DVC=3
2011-09-20 15:17:45.137 ABRA[13133:207] 1 dvc 2
2011-09-20 15:17:45.138 ABRA[13133:207] 2 dvc 2
2011-09-20 15:17:45.330 ABRA[13133:207] 3 dvc 8
2011-09-20 15:17:45.330 ABRA[13133:207] 4 dvc 7
```

The first one is good. The app has just started so the detailViewController retain count is zero, as this is the first entry into the tableView method.

After the alloc, the count is 2 (I'd have thought it should be 1)!

The pushViewController bumps this up to 9, then I release at the end of the method to relinquish ownership (count 8).

After the controller is "popped" (by pressing the Left nav bar button) and the Root vew displays again, the count is still 3 (one for the getter/setter and apparently 2 other things that still hold references to it).

So when another new instance is created and applied via the setter, the count of the old object would still be 2, so it is retained even though it is replaced by the new instance via the synthasized setter.

Further iterations echo the "2,2,8,7,3" result ad infinitum.  Instruments does not count this as a leak, but I sure do because the footprint is growing!

Why is the -alloc/-initWithNib resulting in a retain count of 2 and not 1?
Why does the push increment the retain count 7 the first time and 6 subsequently?
How can I find what is holding onto it when it should have been released?

Comment: `retainCount` ain't gonna tell you jack.  Useless method.  Don't call it.  If you want to track down a leak, use the Allocations instrument and, more specifically, Heapshot analysis.  The leaks tool *may* help, but probably not.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the -alloc/-initWithNib resulting in a retain count of 2 and
>   not 1? Why does the push increment the retain count 7 the first time
>   and 6 subsequently? How can I find what is holding onto it when it
>   should have been released?

@property (nonatomic, **retain**) DetailViewController *detailViewController;

This should answer part of your answer. Your property also retains your view controller. Fix this, and see if your situation improves. (Don't bother putting it in property, just init a local variable and release at the end of the method, the NavigationController will retain the viewController for you)

It is hard to answer the 2nd part of your question, simply because we don't know what happens with detailItem property on detailViewController. Just fix the above, and edit your answer with progress.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that retainCount is generally unreliable for debugging leaks.

Have you tried this change:  (Basically do a lazy load of the dVC?)

```
tableView:didselectRowAtIndexPath call (NSLog's added to show progressive retain count):
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"1 dvc %i",[self.detailViewController retainCount]);
    if (!self.detailViewController) {
        self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
        NSLog(@"2 dvc %i",[self.detailViewController retainCount]);
    }
    NSManagedObject *selectedObject = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    detailViewController.detailItem = selectedObject;    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"3 dvc %i",[self.detailViewController retainCount]);
  // release dVC in your dealloc
  //  [self.detailViewController release];
  //  NSLog(@"4 dvc %i",[self.detailViewController retainCount]);

}
```

Better yet, why not use an IBOutlet for your dVC?

Comment: Running out of ideas, so refactored along those lines (Plan C -- one DetailViewController is retained and reconfigured when the dataset changes).  Waiting for ARC to go Gold is probably the best solution, but time is against me.

Comment: I rarely use initWithNibName and instead use IBOutlets to make it easier.

Comment: self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:nil];
counts for two retains.  Once because of the alloc/init and once for the setter self.detailViewController doing a retain.